# How to format numeric string using C.Gridview - Yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I've recently run into the issue where I have a string of numbers (totaldue)  that I would like to format in my C.Gridview so that 10000 would become 10,000

So far I have done this

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'paylist-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(

    'totaldue'=> array(
        'value'=>'totaldue',         
        'type'=>'number'),
// more code ...
```

This would work if total due was a int or double, but because it is a string, I am getting thrown an error.

I attempted to change number into an int by using intval 
ex.

```
'totaldue'=> array(
        'value'=>intval('totaldue'),          
        'type'=>'number'),
// more code ...
```

but this threw back the error call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given. I know that this can be done - but I'm struggling to implement it. Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

try

```
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'totaldue',
        'value' => 'number_format($data->totaldue)'
    )
 ...
```

Comment: Didnot work, I have tried `'value'=>'number_format($model->minutes)',`